# How to evaluate block of data in excel?

Tags: excel, logic

In excel I'm having data of below Format (Sorry for formatting, I was not allowed to upload image by admin)

1. pass pass pass
2. pass pass pass
3. fail pass pass

Now:

- 1, 2 rows --> Valid PASS, as A, B, C passed
- 3 --> Invalid PASS, as A failed

Please help me write a formula which counts the rows which has all columns "pass" (No Macros Please, its blocked in our institute)
Ex: #1,2 Rows are valid PASS, I need to count all such valid PASS rows in the sheet, which is 2 in above snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to do a count, you can try a `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="PASS"), --(B:B="PASS"),--(C:C="PASS"))
```

Or a `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Pass",B:B, "Pass",C:C,"Pass")
```

Comment: Thanks  RocketDonkey, the solution you suggested was brilliant.. :)

Comment: @AnveshYalamarthy Happy it helped - good luck with everything!